# Visual Studio 2022 expands #pragma region by itself for no known reason

Tags: visual-studio, ide, editor, visual-studio-2022, region

Visual Studio 2022 sometimes expands a random amount of #pragma region region by itself, I don't know why it does it, but it is really annoying and I could not find a solution for it online.

Clarification:

[image: Region example]

As you can see in the image, there are 3 regions.

Region 1 and 2 are collapsed, region 3 is expanded.

Now sometimes Visual Studio randomly expands a couple of regions and jumps to one of them. In our example that might be MyRegion1 and MyRegion2.

Why does this happen, and how can I get it to stop happening?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'd consider filing an issue ticket and adding a link to it here to get extra eyes on this.